# Discover what window is active on Gnome/Linux/Ubuntu from Python?

Tags: python, linux, gnome, window-managers, metacity

Is there any way to get a list of all windows that are open at present and see what window is at the top (i.e. active?) from Python?

This is using Gnome on Ubuntu Linux.

wnck looks like it might do this, but it's very lacking in documentation.

Comment: The [C documentation](http://library.gnome.org/devel/libwnck/stable/) or [Perl documentation](http://gtk2-perl.sourceforge.net/doc/pod/Gnome2/Wnck/index.html) is probably what you need. The Python is not very different.

Comment: See [Obtain Active window using Python](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36419702/562769)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
import wnck
screen = wnck.screen_get_default()
window_list = screen.get_windows()
active_window = screen.get_active_window()
```

See also [Get active window title in X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3983946/get-active-window-title-in-x), and WnckScreen in the documentation. Other [questions containing wnck](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=wnck) have useful code samples.

Comment: Please note that this will always return the same window when queried repeatedly, even when that window is no longer active. To update the state, you have to flush the Gtk event queue and call `force_update` explicitly before calling `get_active_window`. Look at this gist for an example: https://gist.github.com/adewes/6960581

Answer (score 12):

Here's the same code using the modern GObject Introspection libraries instead of the now deprecated PyGTK method Josh Lee posted:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, Wnck

Gtk.init([])  # necessary if not using a Gtk.main() loop
screen = Wnck.Screen.get_default()
screen.force_update()  # recommended per Wnck documentation

window_list = screen.get_windows()
active_window = screen.get_active_window()
```

As for documentation, check out the [Libwnck Reference Manual](https://developer.gnome.org/libwnck/stable/). It is not specific for python, but the whole point of using GObject Introspection is to have the same API across all languages, thanks to the `gir` bindings.

Also, Ubuntu ships with both `wnck` and its corresponding `gir` binding out of the box, but if you need to install them:

```
sudo apt-get install libwnck-3-* gir1.2-wnck-3.0
```

This will also install `libwnck-3-dev`, which is not necessary but will install useful documentation you can read using [DevHelp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devhelp)

Comment: I think this is the real up-to-date answer here. Thanks.

Comment: @MestreLion Hm. Interesting. Ok, my code seems to be the problem. I've removed my commend. Thank you for helping me!