# Determining active window / application with wnck (python) fails

Tags: python, user-interface, wnck

in my python-script i have to determine the actual active window / application to react on remote-events (lirc) application dependent. So i tried to relaize it like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935863/discover-what-window-is-active-on-gnome-linux-ubuntu-from-python). But the test-code

```
import wnck, time

run = True
while run:
    try:
        time.sleep(1)
        screen = wnck.screen_get_default()
        #screen.force_update()
        print screen.get_active_window().get_name()
        print screen.get_previously_active_window()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        run = False
```

results in this output

```
.lirc : python — Konsole
None
.lirc : python — Konsole
None
.lirc : python — Konsole
None
.lirc : python — Konsole
None
.lirc : python — Konsole
None
```

even if i switch to another window. Therefore i repeated the execution and delayed it with `time.sleep(1)`. Executed by a remote-event (lirc) the result is the same. Only within the python shell it seams to work (there `screen.get_previously_active_window()` has a / the right result). The script has been executed within a terminal window (konsole) of Kubuntu 16.04. I've tested to insert `screen.force_update()`, but without success.

What i'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've solved it now with the Xlib. This way it works independent. Here's an example-code:

```
import Xlib
import Xlib.display
import time

run = True
while run:
    try:
        time.sleep(1)

        display = Xlib.display.Display()
        root = display.screen().root
        windowID = root.get_full_property(display.intern_atom('_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW'), Xlib.X.AnyPropertyType).value[0]
        window = display.create_resource_object('window', windowID)

        print window.get_wm_name()
        print window.get_full_property(display.intern_atom('_NET_WM_PID'), Xlib.X.AnyPropertyType).value[0]
        print window.get_full_property(display.intern_atom('_NET_WM_NAME'), Xlib.X.AnyPropertyType).value[0]
        print window.get_full_property(display.intern_atom('_NET_WM_VISIBLE_NAME'), Xlib.X.AnyPropertyType)
        print window.get_wm_class()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        run = False
```

There are shown some possible informations about the window. In my final script I'm using `window.get_wm_class()`.