# Get window position & size with python

Tags: python, windows

How can I get and set the window (any windows program) position and size with python?

Comment: A window owned by the current process, or any top-level window shown on the desktop?

Comment: I'd like to know if there is any way to do this without having to install third party software or non-native libraries. It seems logically that it should be possible. If not though, then why not?.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Assuming you're on Windows, try using `pywin32`'s `win32gui` module with its `EnumWindows` and `GetWindowRect` functions.

If you're using Mac OS X, you could try using `appscript`.

For Linux, you can try one of the many interfaces to X11.

**Edit:** Example for Windows (not tested):

```
import win32gui

def callback(hwnd, extra):
    rect = win32gui.GetWindowRect(hwnd)
    x = rect[0]
    y = rect[1]
    w = rect[2] - x
    h = rect[3] - y
    print("Window %s:" % win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd))
    print("\tLocation: (%d, %d)" % (x, y))
    print("\t    Size: (%d, %d)" % (w, h))

def main():
    win32gui.EnumWindows(callback, None)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: could you give me an example for windows?

Comment: Any suggestions on how to do it under linux (preferably gnome)?

Comment: @seler: As my answer said, you can try one of the interfaces to X11. Personally, I'd use [xpyb](http://xcb.freedesktop.org/XcbPythonBinding/). Iterate through the windows, finding the ones you want, and then get their geometries. The geometries contain the position and size of the windows.

Comment: for a linux solution, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380784/how-to-get-list-opened-windows-in-pygtk-or-gtk-in-ubuntu

Comment: does not work for me: open windows calculator, make it to full screen on full hd monitor and getting strange value: Window Calculator:
 Location: (-7, -7)
     Size: (1550, 838). It has strict disproportion for 1.25 rate and stable shift  for -7, -7 for top left point. looks really strange

Comment: @user2602807 any idea on how to fix these issues? I also face the same

Comment: what hwnd means!?

Answer (score 16):

You can get the window coordinates using the [`GetWindowRect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633519%28VS.85%29.aspx) function. For this, you need a handle to the window, which you can get using [`FindWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), assuming you know something about the window (such as its title).

To call Win32 API functions from Python, use [`pywin32`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/).

Comment: + For suggesting to use FindWindow instead of enum

Answer (score 9):

As Greg Hewgill mentioned, if you know the name of the window, you can simply use [win32gui](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32)'s FindWindow, and GetWindowRect. This is perhaps a little cleaner and efficient than previous methods.

```
from win32gui import FindWindow, GetWindowRect

# FindWindow takes the Window Class name (can be None if unknown), and the window's display text. 
window_handle = FindWindow(None, "Diablo II")
window_rect   = GetWindowRect(window_handle)

print(window_rect)
#(0, 0, 800, 600)
```

<sup>For future reference: PyWin32GUI has now moved to Github</sup>

Comment: I'm getting `(-32000, -32000, -31840, -31972)` when the window is fullscreen (e.g. Diablo / Overwatch)

Answer (score 7):

this can return window rect from window title

#### Code

```py
import ctypes
from ctypes.wintypes import HWND, DWORD, RECT

def GetWindowRectFromName(name:str)-> tuple:
    hwnd = ctypes.windll.user32.FindWindowW(0, name)
    rect = ctypes.wintypes.RECT()
    ctypes.windll.user32.GetWindowRect(hwnd, ctypes.pointer(rect))
    # print(hwnd)
    # print(rect)
    return (rect.left, rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(GetWindowRectFromName('CALC'))
    pass
```

#### Environment

Python 3.8.2 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Apr 24 2020, 07:34:03) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Windows 10 Pro 1909

Comment: if you using windows, `ctypes.windll.user32` and `ctypes.wintypes` are loaded on default.

Answer (score 4):

For Linux you can use the tool I made [here](https://github.com/Pithikos/winlaunch). The tool was meant for a slightly different use but you can use the API directly for your needs.

Install tool

```
sudo apt-get install xdotool xprop xwininfo
git clone https://github.com/Pithikos/winlaunch.git && cd winlaunch
```

In terminal

```
>>> from winlaunch import *
>>> wid, pid = launch('firefox')
>>> win_pos(wid)
[3210, 726]
```

`wid` and `pid` stand for window id and process id respectively.

Comment: Thx a lot for this tool!

Answer (score 3):

This code will work on windows. It return the position and size of the active window.

```
from win32gui import GetWindowRect, GetForegroundWindow
print(GetWindowRect(GetForegroundWindow()))
```

Answer (score 2):

Something not mentioned in any of the other responses is that in newer Windows (Vista and up), "[the Window Rect now includes the area occupied by the drop shadow.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowrect#remarks)", which is what `win32gui.GetWindowRect` and `ctypes.windll.user32.GetWindowRect` are interfacing with.

If you want to get the positions and sizes *without* the dropshadow, you can:

1. Manually remove them. In my case there were 10 pixels on the left, bottom and right which had to be pruned.
2. Use the `dwmapi` to extract the `DWMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS` as mentioned in the article

On using the `dwmapi.DwmGetWindowAttribute` (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwmapi/nf-dwmapi-dwmgetwindowattribute)):

This function takes four arguments: The hwnd, the identifier for the attribute we are interested in, a pointer for the data structure in which to write the attribute, the size of this data structure. The identifier we get by checking [this enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwmapi/ne-dwmapi-dwmwindowattribute). In our case, the attribute `DWMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS` is on position 9.

```py
import ctypes
from ctypes.wintypes import HWND, DWORD, RECT

dwmapi = ctypes.WinDLL("dwmapi")

hwnd = 133116    # refer to the other answers on how to find the hwnd of your window

rect = RECT()
DMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS = 9
dwmapi.DwmGetWindowAttribute(HWND(hwnd), DWORD(DMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS),
                             ctypes.byref(rect), ctypes.sizeof(rect))

print(rect.left, rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom)
```

Lastly: "Note that unlike the Window Rect, the DWM Extended Frame Bounds are not adjusted for DPI".

Answer (score 0):

None of these solutions worked for me on Mac/OSX. Most functions from `pygetwindow` are not implemented for OSX at this time (see `pygetwindow/_pygetwindow_macos.py` [on Github](https://github.com/asweigart/PyGetWindow/blob/master/src/pygetwindow/_pygetwindow_macos.py)).

Using the few functions that *are* implemented, this code will list all windows by name, then fetch each window's geometry in the format (top-left-X, top-left-Y, width, height):

```py
import pygetwindow as gw # pip3 install pygetwindow

windows = gw.getAllTitles()
for win in windows:
    geometry = gw.getWindowGeometry(win)
    print(f'Window title: {win}')
    print(f'> top-left X coordinate: {geometry[0]}')
    print(f'> top-left Y coordinate: {geometry[1]}')
    print(f'> width: {geometry[2]}')
    print(f'> height: {geometry[3]}\n')
```

Example output:

```
Window title: iTerm2 IPython: ~/
> top-left X coordinate: 597.0
> top-left Y coordinate: 178.0
> width: 843.0
> height: 722.0

Window title: Google Chrome Get window position & size with python - Stack Overflow
> top-left X coordinate: 0.0
> top-left Y coordinate: 25.0
> width: 815.0
> height: 875.0

Window title: Finder Macintosh HD
> top-left X coordinate: 260.0
> top-left Y coordinate: 135.0
> width: 920.0
> height: 436.0
```

For reference, list of currently implemented `pygetwindow` functions:

```
- gw.getActiveWindow()
- gw.getAllTitles()
- gw.getWindowsAt()
- gw.getWindowGeometry(title)
```

This is working for me with this environment:

```
Python 3.11.6
PyGetWindow 0.0.9
OSX Ventura 13.5
```