# Python window detection

Tags: python, bots

I'm writing a simple Bot in python using PIL and winPy libraries for Minesweeper. I have one problem with the window detection. For now before I start the Bot execution I wrote a simple piece of code, that I click in the left corner of the window to find a certain pixel combination so the bot has a anchor point of making screenshots and navigating around. I wonder if there is any possible way to just "Find" the window over some win32 module so I "know" where  to make screenshots of the window to get the data for my bot. I'm a heavy beginner so a hard solution I may not understand.

Comment: [Possibly related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142342/get-window-position-size-with-python)

Comment: Thanks alot, that's what I was looking for :)