# write a script in python to save the state of opened windows in ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu

I want to write a python script by which i can save the opened window states same way in mac so that all the window can be loaded automatically when computer restarts or starts after force shutdown

example :  I was using visual code and my computer directly shutdown due to some reason so, next time when i start my computer the visual code will automatically opens up with the same file which i'am working on

same as in mac

Comment: Ok. What's your question? And it needs to be something more specific than "how do I do it?".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get window position & size with python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142342/get-window-position-size-with-python)

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/203952/how-to-automatically-remember-running-applications-from-your-last-session-in-ubuntu-14.04/

Comment: thanks Johnny mopp for the link it realy helps but i still want to write my own script which can do this