# PIL ImageGrab to capture the selected window in Python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

How can I use `ImageGrab.grab())` in a specific manner to capture the selected window rather than the whole screen or boundary box?

For a better understanding, I am currently using this line below, which basically captures the given boundary box:

```
        screen =  np.array(ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(0,40,800,640)))
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hi did you ever find a solution for this?? Python plays GTA?? Thanks

Comment: Hi @HenryHub I did find a solution here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142342/get-window-position-size-with-python)

Answer (score 2):

After finding out of a package, called win32gui I have successfully solved this issue. Please refer to this link: [Get window position & size with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142342/get-window-position-size-with-python)