# Python: how to get window size and location in mac

Tags: python, macos

how can I get the size and position of an active window in mac with python?

Comment: No, that answer  only works in windows, I need the mac version

Comment: I have no experience with this, but apparently this kind of data is aviailable via applescript: http://macosxautomation.com/applescript/firsttutorial/10.html

Comment: I have some old code that may work for you, it's not tested though as I don't own a mac - https://github.com/huntfx/MouseTracks/blob/master/mousetracks/utils/os/mac/appkit/__init__.py

Comment: I was able to get this working on OSX in Python3 with `pygetwindow` - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/77406474/2418744

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: I have no mac to test on.

It seems you can do this with applescript:

```
tell application "Finder" to get position of front window
```

and to set:

```
tell application "Finder" to set {x, y} to position of front window
```

See the [command reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html) for more.

There are also libraries, e.g. https://github.com/rdhyee/py-applescript