# Get window position & size with python -- OS/system agnostic

Tags: python

There are a number of topics ([Get window position & size with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142342/get-window-position-size-with-python)) that address how to get the position and size of a window on an individual OS basis.

Is there a way to do this that's system-agnostic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about a system-agnostic way of handling it, but when ever I run into an issue related to system specific operations. I will insert a platform check.

```
from sys import platform
if platform == "linux":
    # linux
elif platform == "darwin":
    # OS X
elif platform == "windows":
    # Windows...
```

From there I can write out the appropriate operations for what ever task I need to complete on each platform.

Comment: That's a great idea, if no one comes in with an explicit answer I'll accept this one in a few days. I'm not amazingly keen on re-writing things on a per OS basis (OS X and Windows in my case) but if it works it works!

Comment: @Stevphen There are a number of operations that are OS-specific, and the only way around it is to check the platform that you're on and set flags for the operations. So, while there may be a single way to do what you're looking at across all platforms, it's not uncommon that some operations will need to be handled this way. Best of luck.

Comment: That makes sense, however I'm able to (without refactor) run a lot of my python code across both OSx and Windows so I was hoping (despite no luck googling!) there would be a way to at least evaluate window size and position. It's for GUI interactions on the same application across both operating systems, so I figured I can define a function to establish the % of the window (x, y) to interaction with.