# Node.js Windows 10/11: How to set the position of a window?

Tags: node.js, windows, process, position

Is it possible to set/get the position of other windows in node.js in Windows 10/11?

One of my windows keeps moving to my first monitor when Windows goes to sleep / the monitors turn off and it's extremely annoying.

Just want to make a quick script that can get/set a window's position by name.

**Example:**
Say I want to move the window "Discord" to x: 60, y: 55, how would I accomplish this in node.js?

Comment: Node.js is not the best tool for that job. Perhaps you have more luck with python: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7142360/5781499

Answer (score 0):

I use [node-window-manager](https://github.com/sentialx/node-window-manager) it works pretty well for these tasks. You an also use AutoHotKey from node in a few different packages, which would be useful for "if window then". There are also "real" window managers that keep windows in specific regions, screens, virtual displays, etc.