# Is it possible to get the coordinates of an open window with a mouse click using Python?

Tags: python, tkinter, screenshot

I am currently developing an app to take specialized screenshots for work using Python and Tkinter. While I have already implemented a click-and-drag process for a screenshot, I want to add another way to take a screenshot by simply clicking on an open app window, such as a browser, and get its coordinates and use those for a screenshot.

My problem is that I cannot find a way to get a window's coordinates with a mouse click in Python. Is this even possible?

I have not been able to find a way to even try what I want but the functionality of the Windows Snipping Tool (window mode) is what I'm trying to replicate.

Comment: @MattDMo OP does not want the position of the mouse click.  OP wants to get the position and size of the window under the mouse click.

Comment: @acw1668 you're right, the problem statement wasn't worded very clearly. Dupe revoked.

Comment: You can use [PyAutoGUI](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to get the coordinates of a click, [PyGetWindow](https://pygetwindow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to get the coordinates of a window.

Comment: Looks like some good info in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3260559/how-to-get-a-window-or-fullscreen-screenshot-without-pil

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get window position & size with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142342/get-window-position-size-with-python)